# Rendering graphics in R Markdown

Tags: r, graphics, r-markdown

I have been using R Markdown to reproduce R code and report on some data processing. In terms of plotting, there is a difference between what is output to the RStudio IDE and what is rendered via knitr in html. The follwing is the code that applies to both situations

```
barplot(top10summariseDamage$totalDamage, 
        names.arg = c('Hurricane Opal','Heavy Rain/Severe Weather', 
                      'Tornadoes, TSTM Wind, Hail', 'Severe Thunderstorm',
                      'Wild Fires', 'Hail Storm', 'Major Flood',
                      'Hurricane Opal/High Winds', 'Winter Storm/High Winds',
                      'Record Cold'), 
        ylim = c(0, 5*10^10), las = 2, ylab = 'Dollars Damage ($)', 
        main = "Economic Damage by Event Type")
```

The following is a dput of the vector being plotted, where I have added commas to the number for additional clarity

```
c(31728479000, 2.5e+10, 16000002500, 12053600200,  6.241e+09, 
 2.41e+09, 1.05e+09, 1000010000,  600005000,  5.6e+08)
```

Which in RStudio correctly produces the following 
[image]
As you can see the left most bar is less than 4e10. However, when I use knitr to produce an html report, the following is rendered

[image]

As you can see the bar values are literally off the scale, even though I increased the y axis by a factor of 10. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide your data with `dput()`.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have added the dput date below the plot function call where I have added commas for clarity. the highest value is 2.5e10 and ylim= c(0,5*10^10).  I also tried changing 5*10^10 to 5e10 but the output of the html is the same.

Comment: Stackoverflow will not allow me to edit my own comments. 'dput date' should be 'dput data'

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Maybe you have set any graphical options prior to this plot.

Comment: @Martin. It has something to do with the knit -> html process. Can you suggest anything ?

Comment: This this is woring fine for me, I cant. Update all packages is the only thing that comes to my mind.